# Wants to Populate HTML table with objects containing an array using Vue 2.*

Tags: laravel, html-table, vue.js, vue-component

> data:  [ {"column_name":"respond_by","old_value":"0000-00-00
>   00:00:00","new_value":"2017-12-06 00:00:00"},
>
> {"column_name":"client_id","old_value":"163270275","new_value":"535987752"},
>
> {"column_name":"violation_date","old_value":"0000-00-00
>   00:00:00","new_value":"2017-10-23 00:00:00"} ]

this is my HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="value in this.caseDetails">
        <td>{{ value.column_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ value.old_value }}</td>
        <td>{{ value.new_value}}</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like the Column Name to go in the first column and the 2nd Column is for the old Value and the 3rd is for the New Value. Hope someone with more Vue knowledge is able to help me out here.

Comment: What's the problem you're running into? You seem to have everything set up correctly in your HTML. The only thing I see immediately is that your data isn't structured correctly. Specifically, it should be `data: { caseDetails: [ { ... }, { ... }, { ... } ]`, whereas you have `data: [ { ... }, { ... }, { ... } ]`.

Comment: As mentioned by @B.Fleming you need to give key to the table data. Also you need to change the for loop to `v-for="value in caseDetails"`